# Power BI / DAX - Number of clients on each level of sales funnel

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate number of customers on every level of sales funnel. On the sales process client have to go through several statuses depending on actions he/she already took. It's very easy to count number of ID with every status, but to have proper sales funnel I need to be able to SUM upwards number of clients on statuses. 
For example: 100 clients have reached the end of funnel - bought product x. To get there they passed through earlier statuses like e-mail address confirmed, account created, wisited webpage, clicked in advert, received marketing e-mail. 
So to count how many clients were on earlier statuses I need to SUM clients who bought products + clients who confirmed email address, then add those who created account, and so on... 
The trick is to do it in one measure, because to use "Funnel" visualization I can just put one measure as values and statuses as categories.

Comment: There is not enough specificity here to be able to answer. I don't even see a question. An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help greatly.

Comment: I'm on live connection to data Warehouse. There in the fact table I have aggregate with daily customers count, I can filter it for example by status they are on at certain day. Rest is described above